# How do you create a .proto file?

Tags: protocols, protocol-buffers

For a project we're using the Google Protocol Buffers. I'm totally new to this, so I wanted to go through some tutorials. But every tutorial just says: "make a .proto file", but I have no idea how to actually do that... Can it be done with nano? TextEditor? Eclipse? ...?

Answer (score 0):

Use any text editor, like vi, nano, gedit, notepad, notepad++, ...

Example proto

`message Car {
  required string model = 1;
  required int capacity = 2;
  optional int doors = 3;
}`

Save the file named `Car.proto` as an example

Answer (score 0):

The .proto file defines the types you want to be able to serialize and deserialize. You can use any text editor to create a .proto file. If you'd like to have syntax highlighting there are also editors that would give you that. I use IntelliJ but a quick Google search found an Eclipse plugin which appears to be free: https://code.google.com/p/protobuf-dt/.